# Update MySQL table after merging rows

Tags: mysql, merge, sql-update

After executing the following code:

```
SELECT 
    industry, 
    company, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(symbol SEPARATOR ',') AS symbol 
FROM 
    table1
GROUP BY 
    SOUNDEX(company),
```

I managed to merge some rows, however the table isn't updating itself with the merged rows and cells.
I then tried using `UPDATE / SET / WHERE` but not quite sure what to `SET` and `WHERE` as I need to update every merged row/cell. The "best error" that I get is `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

I'm now quite stuck here.. any hint at how to update the table would be much appreciated.

**EDITED**
Some more details:

I'm making a PHP code that can feed data from xml to database, then look for duplicate entries and merge it like this:

*here is the snapshot of my DB table:*
[image: before merging]

When I run code above code through PHP - there are no changes to the above DB table

But when the code is executed directly in phpMyAdmin "SQL", the following changes can be seen:

[image: after merging]

But when I click back to "Browse", all data stays as it was.

Thus it let me think that it is not updating after I did merging...

Comment: Post your sample data and the expected result.  It's completely unclear what kind of table update you have in mind.

Comment: Soundex is fun, but can it really serve a practical purpose?

Comment: Yes, `SOUNDEX` seems to work nice in my case.